# Initializing Multi-Array with zeros

Tags: c++

I'm trying to fill my two Multi Arrays with zero, I allready found some solution here on Stack but it's not working in my case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Const
    const int N_GRIDSIZE=512;
    const int N_ATOMS_R=1000;
    const int N_ATOMS_C = 4;

    //define grid and atoms
    double grid[N_GRIDSIZE][N_GRIDSIZE][N_GRIDSIZE];
    double atom[N_ATOMS_R][N_ATOMS_C];

    memset(grid,0, sizeof(grid));
    memset(atom,0, sizeof(atom));

    return 0;}
```

of course i could iterate over the whole arrays but is there a better solution?
I also tried to do

```
double grid[N_GRIDSIZE][N_GRIDSIZE][N_GRIDSIZE]={};
double atom[N_ATOMS_R][N_ATOMS_C]={};
```

same result!

I'm getting a:
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) which is a segmentation fault

Comment: put `double grid[N_GRIDSIZE][N_GRIDSIZE][N_GRIDSIZE]={0};` as global variable

Comment: thank you worked very well, can you explain whats the difference?

Comment: The difference is: As you did it (declaring in a function) the _storage class_ is implicitly set to `auto` i.e. space for variables is allocated on stack. If you make it global variables the storage class is implicitly set to `extern` and memory is allocated in data segment. Hence, setting the storage class explicitly to `static` or `extern` would work as well as making `grid` and `atom` global variables. E.g. try `static double grid[N_GRIDSIZE][N_GRIDSIZE][N_GRIDSIZE];` and `static double atom[N_ATOMS_R][N_ATOMS_C];` Now, it even works inside of `main()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: Here a link [storage class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). (Wanted to edit in but comment became too long.)

Comment: And, please, don't confuse _storage class_ with C++ `class`. The term was coined even before C++ was invented - for C and was taken over...

Comment: Your problem is that you don't have available memory (on stack). Both your version would initialize your huge array to `0`.